# Check attribute of element HTML

Tags: javascript, html, cypress

I would like to click on an element and check if the `selected` attribute is `true`

Here is my code

```
function clickOnInterface(pos, interfaceName) {
    cy.get('[data-test="interface-list"]').contains(interfaceName).click();

    cy.get(`[data-test="interface-list"] ix-event-list-item:nth-child(${pos})`)
        .should("have.attr", "selected", "true");
    }
```

Cypress gives me this error:

> Timed out retrying after 20000ms: expected
> '<ix-event-list-item.hydrated>' to have attribute 'selected' with the
> value 'true', but the value was 'selected'

I don't understand why it has problem here. Since my attribute is `selected="true"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `cy.get(selector).contains(some-text)` the element returned is the element containing the text, within the element represented by `selector`.

So in your case you end up with `div.event-header`, but what you really need is `ix-event-list-item`, since that is where the `selected` attribute is.

To go to the correct element,

- use `cy.contains(selector, some-text)` format to target the exact element
- use `.should('have.attr', 'selected', 'true')` to test the attribute and it's value

```js
cy.get('[data-test="interface-list"] ix-event-list-item .event-header')
  .each(($item) => {
    clickOnInterface($item.text());
  })

function clickOnInterface(interfaceName) {
  cy.get('[data-test="interface-list"]').contains(interfaceName).click();

  cy.contains('[data-test="interface-list"] ix-event-list-item', interfaceName)
    .should('have.attr', 'selected', 'true');
}
```

Note `cy.get('[data-test="interface-list"]').contains(interfaceName).click()` should be ok if the event bubbles, i.e moves up and down the HTML hierarchy.

If not, the same approach should be used on that line.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! Unfortunately i am still getting the same error as i posted above :/

Comment: I tried your code and it worked with other attributes ( if you check the screenshot i have also color=color-primary) . Is it possible that it doesn't work in my case because selected has boolean value?

Comment: AFIK in HTML every attribute value is a string - if you extract the attribute and test the type of it's value `.invoke('attr', 'selected').then(value => console.log(typeof value))` it should print out `string`.

Comment: Ah yes you are right. Ok i guess there is another issue then.. I will mark your answer as correct since it's working for other attributes and i will try to debug my code. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass 3 arguments to the should function. Can you try this snippet below.

```js
cy.get('[data-test="interface-list"]') {
  cy.get('a').should('have.attr', 'selected', 'true');
}
```

Source: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should

Comment: Thank you for the reply! My biggest problem i think is that if you check the screenshot there are 4 network interfaces (Ethernet 3,WI-FI,etc...) So when i try to use similar approaches like your code, it checks all the elements, therefore is passes always because it can find the selected=true somewhere. That's why i have .contains(interfaceName) to specify only 1.